# URL in kohana 3.3, problems with index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana

I am new to kohana, and for some days now i have been having trouble going to an action in a controller withou using index.php. I always get the error "Requested url was not found on the server"
below is my .htaccess file

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /njorku.com/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

this is my controller class

```
<?php defined ('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access');

class Controller_Ask extends Controller {

    public function action_index (){
        $quests = ORM::factory('asknjorku_question')->order_by('question_id','desc')->find_all();   
        $view = View::factory('/en/asknjorku/index')->bind('quests',$quests);
        $this->request->response = $view;
    }

}
?>
```

when i go to http://localhost/njorku.com/index.php/ask/index it works but
 http://localhost/njorku.com/ask/index wont work

why is it so, please help me out?

Comment: What happens if you try the normal `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`?

Comment: i stll have the same problem @MikeAnthony

Comment: Where is your *.htaccess* file stored? It should be stored in */njorku.com/*

Answer (score 0):

Besides `.htaccess` you might need to modify your `bootstrap.php` file, `Kohana::init()` call in particular:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/njorku.com/',
    'index_file' => FALSE,
));
```